# Linux mint 18 can't connect to some websites while it can ping them

Tags: linux-mint, dns, internet

I recently installed Linux Mint with following information:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=sylvia
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia"
NAME="Linux Mint"
```

And I noticed that it can't open some particular websites (it stuck at `waiting for www.domainname.etc ....`). Then I tested with ping and I noticed that it can easily ping to those websites. I tested the Open DNS and tweaking the DNS settings but it didn't work. Does anyone know what can cause such problem? I also checked many links but none of them were useful.

Regarding the firewall problems here is the content of `iptable`:

```
sudo iptables -L -n

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some kind of firewall which disables access to those sites for you? Why do you think it's a fault on DNS side?

Comment: If you can ping the website with the domain name, your DNS is working fine.

Comment: I'm not sure about the firewall but I don't think that's the problem because I just installed the OS why it should have a firewall?  DNS is the only thing that I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson Yes, you're right.

Comment: @rush You can check the update. I added the content of `iptable`.

Comment: If you have the message "Waiting for..." it means the name resolution has already been done. So this is not a DNS problem. If it was, `ping` would have problems too. Note however that `ping` is not a tool to troubleshoot DNS problems. `dig` is such a tool.

Comment: And to troubleshoot HTTP(S) connection problems, try `tcptraceroute www.example.com 80` (or 443 for HTTPS) and see what is happening.  Of course, try multiple websites, and you can try multiple clients besides your browser, such as `wget` or `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem once under windows with a MTU not matching my environment. Try

```
ifconfig eth0 mtu 1400 up
```

Comment: I'm not connecting to `eth0` but the wifi. And what is `1400`? here? and what does this command do?

Comment: Then use your wlan0 interface instead of eth0. On ethernet connections, there is usually a mtu (maximum transfer unit) of 1500 bytes. Depending on your internet connection some bytes are used for some overhead and you cannot put full 1500 bytes in. With 1400 you limit your mtu to 1400 bytes. Just give it a try, it is not persistent, a reboot will drop that setting.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the firewall interface.  Turn the firewall off and the problem goes away.  I suspect application gateway settings are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was using *Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon* and was facing this issue for a day or two. I turned off **ufw** from firewall settings and now can connect to any site. Connection response is also faster.

Additionally, there were also other problems like the inability to do fast web scraping using Python or make requests to some APIs, etc.. All of these problems were solved after turning off **ufw logging**.

[image: Annotated screenshot of Firewall and Firewall Preferences dialogs]